# Java ArrayDeque instantiation from existing Collection vs Iteration

Tags: data-structures, collections, java

I am trying to evaluate two of creating an [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) with existing collection.. I see two options :

1. Using ArrayDeque's [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#ArrayDeque(java.util.Collection)) which accepts an existing Collection
2. Iterate over the Collection and call dequeu.offer(element) while iterating over Collection

From my benchmarks I see first option running faster than second. Is there any reason for the first option to be better than second ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first option.

```
public ArrayDeque(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    allocateElements(c.size());
    addAll(c);
}
```

It allocates all the elements in one call (that is, it allocates an array with enough elements) and then just adds them one by one (without any additional allocations).

But when you use option 2, several allocations happen during this process when `ArrayDeque` grows (doubling itself); plus on each reallocation the elements are copied to the new array.

Just one allocation (for option 1) versus several allocations plus copying (for option 2) gives the difference.

For reference:

```
public boolean offerLast(E e) {
    addLast(e);
    return true;
}

public void addLast(E e) {
    if (e == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    elements[tail] = e;
    if ( (tail = (tail + 1) & (elements.length - 1)) == head)
        doubleCapacity();
}
```

All code is from Java 8.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This makes total sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Creating new ArrayDeque with constructor and in way to iterate through Collection and add each element by one is similar. Because in constructor of this class used iteration through all collection.